# Shutter Speed / Average Over Frames for 2D animation

Tags: rendering, animation, export, 2d, frame-rate

I have 1000 frames of 2D animation hand-drawn at 60fps.

I want to render it at 24 fps, but instead of skipping frames, I want to average the nearby frames effectively changing the shutter speed of the animation. Is there a way to do this in Blender?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Video Editor in Blender can do what you want.

1. There is a video effect call speed that will interpolate and change the speed of a sequence of images. This can be used to change from 60fps to 24fps.
2. If the interest is in combining images when doing the conversion from 60fps to 24fps, then the transition effects can be used.

Details for Blender 2.93.4:

1. Open a new blender file for video editing.
2. Load the sequence of images into channel #1.
3. Load the sequence of images into channel #2. Change the start frame to -1. This is done to help approximate the blurring.
4. Select channel #2 and apply the transition effect. Use key framing to set the transition to 0.5 on frame #1 and 0.5 on the last frame. This has the effect of blurring two frames.
5. Select channel #1 and channel #2, then add the speed effect.
6. Set the speed effect to Multiply Speed to 60/24 or 2.50. This will change the frame rate.
7. Adjust the last frame.

This is what the resulting video sequence looks like for a 99 frame video converted from 60 fps to 24 fps.
[image]